# convert json data to proper json object

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

From php i return data using json_encode. Im getting this data trough a angularJS http request. Now when i check my data it looks like this:

```
addons: "[{"a_addonid":"32","a_addongroupid":"20","a_addonname":"rrrrr","a_priceoption":"paid","a_price":"2.00","addongroupid":"20","optiontype":"single","groupname":"bij asdad"}]"
```

it's in proper json format (checked online) but its a string? i want to user ng-repeat on addons but i cant because its not a array or object.

how can i convert this to a array or object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `angular.fromJson()` to convert the data. [<kbd>doc</kbd>](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson)

Comment: and from php: header('Content-Type: application/json');